# Why I got Error 403, while I don't have any authentication form on my website?

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I published a website yesterday, and I don't have any authentication form on my website.

This is my `web.Config` :

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
</system.web>
  <system.webServer>
   <defaultDocument>
       <files>
        <add value="Default.aspx"/>
      </files>
   </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

But when I try to browse my website, it gives me 403 error! I don't have any authentication form on my website, why it's happened?

Answer (score 0):

403 is for access denied/forbidden, can you check your IIS which you have hosted. Looks like some IIS settings like Application Pool, Framework settings.

Looks like Application which its targeting to the framework needs to be explicitly selected.